# Grouping similar jQuery functions

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way to group the following functions into one?

```
$('#box_1 input:checkbox').click(function(){
var $inputs = $('#box_1 input:checkbox')
    if($(this).is(':checked')){
       $inputs.not(this).prop('disabled',true); 
    }else{
       $inputs.prop('disabled',false);
    }
});
$('#box_2 input:checkbox').click(function(){
var $inputs = $('#box_2 input:checkbox')
    if($(this).is(':checked')){
       $inputs.not(this).prop('disabled',true); 
    }else{
       $inputs.prop('disabled',false);
    }
});
```

There are more of the box_id's. Would be great to have a simpler solution than writing 2 km of code

Thanks a lot in advance for helping

Comment: You'd get better help if you showed the HTML, including some of the containing divs and the relationship of the items.  Then, we could probably find one set of selectors/code that could work for all, but  we're flying blind without seeing the structure.  Honestly, it's not worth guessing how to code this without seeing the HTML.

Comment: This looks a lot like the functionality of [radio buttons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radio_button). Why not use [radio buttons](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input) instead of such hacks?

Comment: @rvihne because you can't deselect the radio buttons. I need to select and de-select them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Approach looping over all the outer boxes first

```
$('[id^=box_]').each(function(){    
   var $inputs=$(this).find(':checkbox').change(function(){
        $inputs.not(this).prop('disabled', this.checked);
   });
});
```

ID as attribute selector is a bit ugly, prefer using common class instead

Comment: Great. Short and concise! But i get an error on  `var $inputs.not(this).prop('disabled', this.checked);`

Comment: there was a typing error on that line: the second "var" was too much. Now it's working. Thanks a lot!

Comment: About your comment: But id selector wouldn't be faster?

Comment: @Someone33  ooops   missed it

Comment: faster?  probably not using an attribute selector as I did, class likely faster and easer to read

Comment: would mean adding same class to all of the box_id but if this works isn't likely a big deal

Comment: ah...ok, understanding. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Put a common class on all your `#box_X` elements and use that for targeting

```
$('.common-class').on('click', 'input:checkbox', function(){

    var $inputs = $(this).closest('.common-class').find('input:checkbox');

        if (this.checked) {
           $inputs.not(this).prop('disabled',true); 
        } else {
           $inputs.prop('disabled',false);
        }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Give a common class to your `box` ID's - say "box"

```
$(".box :checkbox").click(function() {
    //reference the current clicked checkbox with 'this'
    //this.id will give the ID of the clicked box
    var $inputs = $(this).siblings("checkbox");
    if (this.checked) {
        $inputs.prop("disabled", true);
        //do checked
    } else {
        //not checked
        $inputs.prop("disabled", false);
    }
});
```

Comment: This doesn't handle changing the other checkbox states in the group like was being done with this line `$inputs.not(this).prop('disabled',true);`.  That is the interesting part of the question - how to solve that with one piece of code for multiple groups of checkboxes.

Comment: @jfriend00 -- Updated to the best I could sans HTML

Comment: Now, you're guessing what the HTML structure looks like.  Might work, might not work.  That's why my comment to the OP says we HAVE to see the HTML to write the best answer.

Comment: Basically just need to convert `var $inputs = $('#box_2 input:checkbox')` to use `closest('.box')`

Answer (score 0):

if nothing else, you could put it in a `for loop` and generate your selector dynamically.

```
for (var i=0; i<n; i++){
    $('#box_' + i + ' input:checkbox').click(function(){
    var $inputs = $('#box_' + i + ' input:checkbox')
        if($(this).is(':checked')){
           $inputs.not(this).prop('disabled',true); 
        }else{
           $inputs.prop('disabled',false);
        }
    });
}
```

A class selector would be more elegant.